# CLI Reset Local Cluster (Rebuild Clusters according to Manifest)

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to figure out the command to rebuild clusters according to the manifest, ie. the equivalent to the tray icon menu entry: Reset Local Cluster.

I run the command I've found as a user who is a member of the Local Administrators, but I get some No Access (Ingen tilgang)

```
PS C:\Users\caec> C:\"Program Files"\"Microsoft SDKs"\"Service Fabric"\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1 -PathToClusterDataRoot c:\SfDevCluster\data -PathToClusterLogRoot c:\SfDevCluster\log -auto
Removing cluster configuration...
Opening TraceWriter FabricDeployer, path c:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\FabricDeployer-638106697980303321.trace
Closing TraceWriter FabricDeployer, path c:\SfDevCluster\log\Traces\FabricDeployer-638106697980303321.trace
Cleaning existing certificates...
Certificates removed.
Stopping all logman sessions...
Cleaning log and data folder...
c:\SfDevCluster\data\_App\_Node_1\INFODO~1.API\INFODO~1.0\mscordbi.dll - Ingen tilgang.
c:\SfDevCluster\data\_App\_Node_3\INFODO~1.API\INFODO~1.0\mscordbi.dll - Ingen tilgang.

Using Cluster Data Root: c:\SfDevCluster\data
Using Cluster Log Root: c:\SfDevCluster\log

c:\SfDevCluster\data\_App\_Node_1\INFODO~1.API\INFODO~1.0\mscordbi.dll - Ingen tilgang.
c:\SfDevCluster\data\_App\_Node_3\INFODO~1.API\INFODO~1.0\mscordbi.dll - Ingen tilgang.
EnsureDirectoryCleaned : Cannot clean up c:\SfDevCluster\data fully as references are likely being held to items in it. Please remove those and retr
y.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:525 char:5
+     EnsureDirectoryCleaned $clusterDataRoot
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,EnsureDirectoryCleaned

WARNING: Hints: Is some other process holding on to references?
ScriptHalted
Stop-Transcript : An error occurred stopping transcription: The host is not currently transcribing.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1:54 char:5
+     Stop-Transcript
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Stop-Transcript], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopTranscriptCommand
```

Comment: Can you try adding a call to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\CleanCluster.ps1` before you call `DevClusterSetup.ps1`?

Comment: Figured it out; I had a devenv process running, so it had a lock on some files;). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a devenv process running, so it had a lock on some files;)